# VBA Help: Iterating through another columns value and creating a separate unique counter *see description*

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Basically this code is reading column 2 which is JP's, and placing JT1,JT2 etc in another column but the catch is this, whenever a new JP is present in the next row, it'll restart the counter and always output JT1, but when there are multiple of the same JP it'll start a counter.

An example is like this:

JP1 --> JT1, JP2 --> JT1, JP2 --> JT2

Notice how when there is a unique JP it always is JT1, but once there is multiple of the same JP, the JT starts a counter like JT1, JT2, JT3 etc.

I am having trouble right now with this any help would be great.

```
Dim JobTask as String
Dim w1 as Workbook
Dim s1 as Worksheet
Dim row1 as Integer
Dim iteration as Integer

set w1 = ThisWorkbook
set s1 = w1.Sheets("Job Plan Sort")

For row1 = 9 To 16
JobPlan = s1.Cells(row1, 2).Value
JobTask = s1.Cells(row1, 3).Value


For iteration = row1 To 16
 If s1.Cells(iteration, 2) <> s1.Cells(iteration + 1, 2) Then

For j = row1 To (counter + row1)
                
                    s1.Cells(j, 3).Value = ("JT" + CStr(jtCounter))
                    
                Next j
                row1 = row1 + counter
                jtCounter = jtCounter + 1
                
                Exit For
                
         End If




            
     Next iteration
   



     Next row1
```

HERE IS SAMPLE OF OUTPUT AS REQUESTED

[image]

Comment: Feel like your request will create `infinite loop`?

Comment: Would really help to show sample input/expected output in your post.

Comment: Sure Ill add a sample

Comment: What about a sample input  dataset?

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
I2: ="JT"&COUNTIF($H$2:H2,H2)
```

[image]